# FullCalendar GMT +0200 on dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am having some troubles with the date in fullcalendar.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    //...
    eventDrop:
        function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view)
        {
            console.log(event.start); // start is a date
        }
);
```

After a drag and drop, I can see in my console :

```
Date {Wed Jul 03 2013 16:50:00 GMT+0200}
```

I would like fullcalendar to show the values in UTC, as GMT+0000. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using the [ignoreTimezone](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/) setting, but it is not helping.  Perhaps I am not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not FullCalendar that is producing the offset you are seeing.  It's just JavaScript's `Date` object.

The behavior of `Date` is that it internally tracks time in UTC, but whenever you display it, the value is presented using the time zone of the local computer.  There isn't any direct way to disable this behavior - that's just how JavaScript dates work.  You can review [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for more information about JavaScript dates.

You might want to consider explicitly outputting the time in UTC.  For example:

```
console.log(event.start.toUTCString());
```

If you are trying to treat the items on the calendar as already being in UTC, that is not a behavior that is supported by FullCalendar.  You could try to "fake it", using something like this:

```
var dt = event.start;
var adjusted = new Date(dt.getTime() - (dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
console.log(adjusted.toUTCString());
```

But you may find interesting or strange behavior around the transition points where daylight saving time starts or ends in the user's local time zone.  The only way to avoid that would be for FullCalendar to allow you to set the time zone of the entire calendar to UTC, which AFAIK does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for helping ! toUTCString is going to convert Date {Wed Jul 03 2013 16:50:00 GMT+0200} into Date {Wed Jul 03 2013 14:50:00}. But I need this Date {Wed Jul 03 2013 16:50:00}, is there a function to have it ?

Comment: That would actually be a different moment in time.  FullCalendar is calibrated to display the calendar of the timezone where it is running.  When you see 16:50 on the calendar, that's 16:50 local time.  AFAIK, there's no way to tell it to render the calendar as UTC, or in any other time zone.